# Mapbox Geocoding and dropping single marker

Tags: javascript, mapbox, markers

I added Mapbox's Geocoder control and the function to have a marker appear in the found location to a map. My problem is that every new search now renders a new marker. What I would like is that once you prompt a new search the old marker disappears and you get a new one. Does this work somehow?

Here is the code I used to add the marker.

```
var geocoderControl = L.mapbox.geocoderControl('mapbox.places', {keepOpen: false, autocomplete: true});
geocoderControl.addTo(map);


geocoderControl.on('select', function(object){
   var coord = object.feature.geometry.coordinates;
   L.marker([coord[1], coord[0]]).addTo(map);
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a marker first without any location information (and without adding it to the map), then just use `.setLatLng` to change its location:

```
var marker = L.marker(false);

geocoderControl.on('select', function(object){
   var coord = object.feature.geometry.coordinates;
   marker.setLatLng([coord[1], coord[0]]).addTo(map);
});
```

The marker is only created once, and it will be moved each time the geocoder picks a location.